# Looping over an array of JSON objects, with JSON objects nested inside of them

Tags: json, reactjs, loops, graphql, gatsby

**UPDATE**: Thank you SO MUCH, Anoop! I spent hours on this...

I'm fetching some nested graphql data, and I believe my original const of "portProjectHolder" is as far as I can reach through . notation.

With my `console.log(portProjectHolder)`, I receive an array with 2 JSON objects - and these 2 json objects each have an object inside of them that I need to fetch the properties from and map them to a card component. However, I have no idea at this point how to do this.

Here is the response I'm getting on my console:

**console.log(portProjectHolder) :**

```
[
    {
        "portfolioProjects": {
            "projectTitle": "Sample Project 2",
            "description": "Project description...sample number 2...hope this works...",
            "image1": {
                "sourceUrl": "https://travelweird.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/dribble-cultivate-icon.png"
            },
            "image2": null,
            "image3": null,
            "image4": null
        }
    },
    {
        "portfolioProjects": {
            "projectTitle": "Sample Project 1",
            "description": "Project description...here's some text, let's see what ya do with it. ",
            "image1": {
                "sourceUrl": "https://travelweird.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/complab123-scaled.jpg"
            },
            "image2": null,
            "image3": null,
            "image4": null
        }
    }
]
```

I need to loop through and map the objects within

Full Code:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

import Card from '../components/Card/Card'

export default function Home({ data }) {
  let portProjectHolder = data.wordPress.projects.nodes

  console.log(portProjectHolder)




 

  return (
      <div>
          {/* <portProjectHolder.map(portProject => { */}
                  <Card 
                    key={portProjects.projectTitle}
                   title={portProjects.projectTitle}
                   description={portProjects.description} 
                    image={portProjects.sourceUrl}
                    />
             {/* I can't for the life of me figure out how to map twice nested objects from an array...*/}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: what is inside portfolioProjects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that, portfolioProjects is not an array, then the solution will be,

```
<div>
      {portProjectHolder.map((portProject) => {
        const project = portProject.portfolioProjects;
        return (
          <Card
            key={project.projectTitle}
            title={project.projectTitle}
            description={project.description}
            image={project.sourceUrl}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: That is nearly perfect - the only thing I'm having trouble pulling now is the SourceUrl since it's in the image object - PortfolioProjects:
description -- updated my post to show return response more clearly

Comment: Nvm - all good now. Just needed to add project.image1.sourceurl